# Why facebook,twitter does not allow to embed or iframe a profile page?

Tags: html, facebook, twitter

I am trying to embed facebook and twitter user's public profile page on my webpage.but nothing showing.

For example

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/SamsungMobile?ref=br_tf"></iframe>
<object type="text/html" data="https://www.facebook.com/SamsungMobile?ref=br_tf"
        style="width:100%; height:100%; margin:1%;">
</object>
```

AND

```
 <iframe src="https://twitter.com/samsungmobile"></iframe>
<object type="text/html" data="https://www.facebook.com/SamsungMobile?ref=br_tf"
        style="width:100%; height:100%; margin:1%;">
</object>
```

What I want to achieve is user will put their social pages link on their setting page.And I want to show those pages on their profile so when a guest user go on their profile he can see their social pages.

Because I want to automate the process that's why could not use social widgets/plugins.

As twitter has a different id for each feed plugin.

Can you please help how I can achieve this?

Comment: The question in the title is very different from the one in the body, which is not a well-defined question eithe.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you use something like [Html2Canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) to render an image of the Twitter or Facebook page, as neither allow their pages to be iframed.